# Determining Relative Weights

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, factor-analysis

I am looking for some recommendations and more specifics about how to do the following:

Objective: To determine the weights of a number of stock valuation metrics. I am looking at doing this across 10 different industry sectors as I expect that each sector will merit a different weighting scheme.

The data I have are:

Monthly average metrics for each sector over approximately 20 years.
I also have return data for each sector on a monthly basis.

I am looking to do this in R Studio.

Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Why did you pick these specific tags? For instance, I don't see why you picked `factor-analysis`? You could also add the `R` tag if you want this in R (and `econometrics` perhaps?).

Comment: What are these "weights" intended to do or represent about the data?

Comment: I am going to use weights in order to build a mechanism to determine whether sectors are under or over valued.

Comment: Thank you--but we really need more specific and quantitative information to go on here. How do you tell what the correct values are in your historical data?